# add dependencies to package.json docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, package.json

I am currently running a nodejs express app in docker.

docker-compose.yml

```
# networks and nginx ...
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    networks:
      - back-tier
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g nodemon
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "nodemon" ]
```

The problem here is the volume is mounted and I can't modify package.json from the host as the docker "owns" package.json.

However if I add a dependency inside the docker with `docker run -it dockername_api /bin/sh` then doing `npm i package`, the package.json does not update in the host side.

The solution now is to manually copy package.json from the container back to host after adding a new dependency? Another way of doing it is to stop the docker, do `npm i package` on the host, then rebuild the docker, which is very cumbersome.

Thanks

Comment: In a development environment, you should not `COPY`, just mount the volume.

Comment: If a Docker-based Node installation is inconvenient, would a host-based Node work better (`apt-get install nodejs`, `brew install node`)?  I'd generally recommend a workflow where you build and test your application locally, then `docker build` to package it into an image, running it without the `volumes:` you show.